# SCons autoconf tests from xcode

Tags: xcode4.3, scons

I am trying to launch scons from within xcode 4 in order to build an external (i.e. not originally created in xcode) c++ project.

I have created a new project with an external build system as advised in the documentation.

Everything works except the autoconf functionality built in scons - it fails to find a library in /usr/lib. Calling scons from the shell (i.e. outside of xcode) works of course.

Since SCons allows to cache config test results, I also tried to run scons from the shell for the first time, hoping that xcode would grab the test results and therefore avoid performing them. It doesn't work - apparently scons is using a different cache when called from the shell or from xcode...

Any suggestions for identifying the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ups, found the solution  after looking into the scons logs more carefully.

The problem was the following argument that xcode passes to the link command:

-syslibroot /Applications/Programming/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk

which may be disabled in the GUI by removing the SDKROOT variable...

Hope it helps somebody
Marco